# No converter found for return value of type: class com.spring.mvc.model.User]

Tags: java

Exception is here:
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [hello] in context with path [/Spring_MVC] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type: class com.spring.mvc.model.User] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type: class com.spring.mvc.model.User

Source code are below:
UserController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    private Map<String,User> users = new HashMap <String, User>();

    public UserController(){
        users.put("wang", new User("wang","pwang","wang a bo","123"));
        users.put("chen", new User("chen","pChen","Chen Lin","1e23"));
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="{userName}",method=RequestMethod.GET, params="json")
    @ResponseBody
    public  User show(@PathVariable String userName) {
        return users.get(userName);
    }   
}
```

User.java

```
public class User {

    @NotEmpty(message="User Name not null!!!")
    private String userName;

    @Size(min=6,max=12,message="Password need 6 to 12 Character!!!")
    private String passWord;

    private String nickName;

    @Email(message="Email Fromat invalide!!")
    private String email;

    public User(){

    }

    public User(String userName, String passWord, String nickName, String email) {
        super();
        this.userName = userName;
        this.passWord = passWord;
        this.nickName = nickName;
        this.email = email;
    }


    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }


    public String getPassWord() {
        return passWord;
    }

    public void setPassWord(String passWord) {
        this.passWord = passWord;
    }

    public String getNickName() {
        return nickName;
    }

    public void setNickName(String nickName) {
        this.nickName = nickName;
    }


    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

Spring-4.3.5-Release
jackon-all-1.9.4.jar

Comment: I have used below jars to replaced jackon-all-1.9.4.jar. This issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used below jars to replaced jar jackon-all-1.9.4.jar. The problem has been resolved.
jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar
jackson-core-2.5.0.jar
jackson-annotations-2.5.0.jar

Comment: com\fasterxml\jackson\core\util\DefaultIndenter.class is a new add class after 2.5. Pls take not on it.